# Best way to store multiple json values for analytics?

Tags: json, database, olap

Suppose one is trying to save such API responses for analytics later, ie, a single response has about a 1000 persons
Each object has about 26 properties.
The API query is made every 5 minutes for example.

```
{person1 : {propertyA:a1, propertyB:b1 ....... propertyZ:z1}
 person2 : {propertyA:a2, propertyB:b2 ....... propertyZ:z2}
 ....
 ....
 person999: {propertyA:a999, propertyB:b999 ....... propertyZ:z999}
 person1000: {propertyA:a1000, propertyB:b1000 ....... propertyZ:z1000}}
```

1. What is the best way to store such kind of data for analytics later? What kind of database? (the simpler the better)
2. Should the multiple responses of such API calls be stored in single rows or make multiple columns for each object? Or some other way like JSON dbs?

Note - the person might change over time, eg `person100` might stop being updated or become inactive .... so an API resposne in future might not include `person100` instead another record for `person1001` might be added (unrelated to `person100` becoming inactive)

Additional info :
Data would be updated say every 5 mins for a say 5 years (to give an idea about usage/retention of data).
Queries would mostly be limited to how a `personX` is changing over a given time frame that is likely to range from a few hours to over 6 months.
Properties of a person are likely to have same/similar profile of attributes, althoug their values would obviously change over time

Answer (score 1):

> the simpler the better

The simplest would presumably be to keep the results of each API query in a single file, though if you did so, it would probably best to use a JSONLines format, with
one line per person. However, in either case, I would almost certainly add an 'id' field to make it trivially easy to query for a particular person, and to migrate the data elsewhere should that become necessary.

A variant of the above would be to have one file per person, again with a JSONLines format, but with the addition of some kind of timestamp.

Next up the ladder of complexity, you might want to consider a SQLite database.  If you want to retain the JSON format, then you'd presumably want to add
indices, e.g. on the person id.

If the JSON object representation of each person is flat and the property list stable, then the conventional wisdom would be to store the data in columnar format.  A reasonable compromise would be to move the properties of interest to columns, and to relegate all the other (relevant) details to JSON-valued columns.

Of course there are umpteen other database options, and you can climb the complexity ladder as high as it goes.  Likewise for cost. You might like to look at [TimescaleDB](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/) for starters.

#### Managing Scale

If the data for an individual does not change very often, there will
presumably be various ways to reduce the redundancy.

At one end of the spectrum of possibilities, you could simply discard
an entire record if the prior retained record for that person is essentially the same.

Towards the other end of the spectrum, you could recast the data as a
series of events that would be easy to store as a table:

```
timestamp id propertyName value
```

This would have the advantage of giving you flexibility w.r.t. both
the universe of persons and the set of properties of interest.

See also https://www.timescale.com/blog/time-series-compression-algorithms-explained/

---

Footnote: The PmWiki system https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PmWiki illustrates how a fairly complex “database” system can be constructed using the underlying file system.

Comment: Single files for each api response doesn't seem very efficient considering analytics is the end use case. Sqlite seems like a better idea - by columnar format what do you mean? Asking since there are columnar DBs as well these days - are those better for analytics? Came across duckdb - not sure if its suitable for this use case

Comment: Your problem statement is underspecified, but you might be pleasantly surprised how fast file access can be.  I'd expect the time to be in the querying, which would presumably be sped up if there were indices on the appropriate fields; depending on the queries, though, you could probably do quite a lot with directories and files.  But without knowing more about the specifics, it is probably pointless to speculate.

Comment: the problem is actually specified to the best of my knowledge - what do you mean by "underspecified"? I could perhaps edit the question to better specify it .... I know it comes across as abstract but there is literally this api call that returns 1000 persons/objects with 20-30 properties ... and need to analyze over time. Let me know if I can add something.

Comment: And I highly doubt file access is a great way - since querying it would be cumbersome

Comment: Please see updates.  You have not specified your cost constraints, your constraints regarding existing expertise and the acquisition of new expertise, the expected retention period of the data, the stability profile of the properties, whether you require "ad hoc" query capabilities,  ...

Comment: Updates with "Additiona Info" in the question above - let me knonw if that helps